# 1.8.8 Minecraft server won't run in Debian Linux

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, linux, server-administration

I'll make this simple.

I run small Minecraft servers on my Raspberry Pi 3B+, and it suffices for very small stuff, but I wanted more power. I grabbed an old Windows laptop that was picking up dust, wiped it, and installed Debian Linux. I copied over the Spigot server folder from my RPi into my laptop, and installed "identical" Java versions.

[image: My Debian laptop showing its Java version]

[image: My raspberrypi showing its Java version]

Running the server on the Pi has always worked flawlessly; however, when I transferred the files to my Debian, and ran them with Java, something strange happened.
The server does claim to start, but when I ping the server in any way (By clicking the `Refresh` button on the servers page), the console ***SHOWERS ME*** in exceptions. They are all the exact same exception, but it spams it for a solid 2 or 3 minutes until I do `Ctrl+C` to make it stop.

[image: The server going nuts]

I believe it's also worth mentioning that the server logs this to the console when ran on the laptop

```
INFO: Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system unstability.
```

I believed it may be an issue with Spigot, but it is not. I manually downloaded the vanilla 1.8.9 server.jar, and ran that alone, to no changes in results.

What could be going on here?

**(The laptop in question is a Toshiba Satellite P875-S7200 running Debian 4.19.132-1 [2020-07-24]
)**

Comment: Regarding your answer: Please don't ask additional questions in those. Quick summary: a library that is used in this nearly 6 years old version of Minecraft is using features that have been redone/removed in later versions of Java (9+) for various reasons. You can either use an older version of Java (8 is recommended) or use a newer version of Minecraft, which does support even the latest versions of Java (currently tested with Java 15 Early Testing)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it worked, or how. But I downloaded the jdk-8 `tar.gz` source, unzipped it, put it on my Debian, and ran the server from there. I was under the impression that Java 11 was backwards compatible. Can someone explain why I'm wrong?

Comment: So to be clear: Did these steps solve your problem?

Comment: Indeed, they did

Comment: 1.8 does not work with Java 11. This is correct. You can also do `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless` and `sudo update-alternatives --config java`, and finally choose Java 8.